# State not updating correctly in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, state, combine

Am trying to implement like and unlike button, to allow a user to like a card and unlike. When a user likes a button the `id` is saved and the icon changes from line heart to filled heart. I can save the `id` correctly but the issue is that at times the icon does not switch to filled one to show the user the changes especially after selecting the first one. The subsequent card won't change state but remain the same, while it will add save the `id` correctly. To be able to see the other card I have to, unlike the first card it cand display both like at the same time. I have tried both `Observable` and `Environmental`.

My Class to handle like and unlike

```
import Foundation
import Disk

class FavouriteRest: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var fav = [Favourite]()
    
    init() {
        getFav()
    }
    
    func getFav(){
        if let retrievedFav = try? Disk.retrieve("MyApp/favourite.json", from: .documents, as: [Favourite].self) {
            fav = retrievedFav
        } else {
            print("")
        }
    }
    
    
    //Get single data
    func singleFave(id: String) -> Bool {
        for x in fav {
            if id == x.id {
               return true
            }
            return false
        }
        return false
    }
    
    func addFav(favourite: Favourite){
        if singleFave(id: favourite.id) == false {
            self.fav.append(favourite)
            self.saveFave()
        }
    }
    
    //Remove Fav
    func removeFav(_ favourite: Favourite) {
        if let index = fav.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == favourite.id }) {
            fav.remove(at: index)
            saveFave()
        }
    }
    
    //Save Fav
    func saveFave(){
        do {
            try Disk.save(self.fav, to: .documents, as: "SmartParking/favourite.json")
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            fatalError("""
                Domain: \(error.domain)
                Code: \(error.code)
                Description: \(error.localizedDescription)
                Failure Reason: \(error.localizedFailureReason ?? "")
                Suggestions: \(error.localizedRecoverySuggestion ?? "")
                """)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Single Card

```
@EnvironmentObject var favourite:FavouriteRest

            HStack(alignment: .top){
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4){
                    Text(self.myViewModel.myModel.title)
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Text("Some text")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Gray"))
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack{
                    self.favourite.singleFave(id: self.myViewModel.myModel.id) ? Heart(image: "suit.heart.fill").foregroundColor(Color.red) : Heart(image: "suit.heart").foregroundColor(Color("Gray"))
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    if self.favourite.singleFave(id: self.myViewModel.myModel.id) {
                        self.favourite.removeFav(Favourite(id: self.myViewModel.myModel.id))
                    } else {
                        self.favourite.addFav(favourite: Favourite(id: self.myViewModel.myModel.id))
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I believe it is because your condition to show either Image is not dependent on any state, but a function: `func singleFave()`. As no state changes, the VStack's body is not recalculated.

Comment: When I select for the first time it works fine.

Comment: I think your `singleFave` function has a bug. As soon as it sees a non-matching id, it returns false. The middle `return false` (the one inside the `for` loop) shouldn't be there, I think (if I understood your code correctly)

Comment: Let me try to make modification and see if it will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the question by moving the code inside the card view and using `@States` as shown below.

```
    @State private var fav = [Favourite]()
    @State var liked = false
    VStack{
       // Heading
       HStack(alignment: .top){
          VStack{
            self.liked ? Heart(image:"suit.heart.fill").foregroundColor(Color.red) : Heart(image: "suit.heart").foregroundColor(Color("Gray"))
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
               if self.liked {
               self.removeFav(self.singleFav!)
            } else {
                   let faveID = self.myViewModel.myModel.id
                   let myFav = Favourite(id:faveID)
                   self.fav.append(myFav)
                   self.saveFave()
           }
        }
   }
```

In the method for fetch and remove, I updated the `@State var liked`. Everything working as expected now.